# how to let -ms-grid adaptive width layout in win8 html and javascript metro app?

Tags: html, css, layout, windows-8, microsoft-metro

my code all in default.html,the html is:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="group" id="left">
            <div>Left_1</div>
            <div>Left_2</div>
            <div>Left_3</div>
            <div>Left_4</div>
            <div>Left_5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group" id="center">
            <div>Center_1</div>
            <div>Center_2</div>
            <div>Center_3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group" id="right">
            <div>Right_1</div>
            <div>Right_2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css is:

```
body {
    font-size:20px;
}

#content {
    display:-ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-rows:1fr;
    -ms-grid-columns:auto auto auto;
    height:100%;
}

.group {
    margin-right:20px;
}

#left {
    -ms-grid-column:1;
}

#center {
    -ms-grid-column:2;
}

#right {
    -ms-grid-column:3;
}

.group div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:#888;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and the result is:
[image]

but i need is :
[image]

how to modify the css?who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by use flexbox:

```
.group {
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:start;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want IE specific code when you can do it using w3c standards which, even on IE, are supported since an older version?

Comment: @Oriol this is win8 metro app,so the browser only ie10

Comment: But I think that's not the point. I think you should do it the right way instead of a way which can work but isn't the best.

Answer (score 3):

You should use flexbox:

```
.container 
{
    display: -ms-flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
}
```

and then place your items in that container, and you should all be good.

I would definitely recommend using flexbox over table-cell for your metro-only application.

There are many additional options for the flexbox layout, which can get really quite complicated. See [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_flex.htm) for hands on (be sure to view in IE10), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the layout you want by using a ListView with its Layout set to GridLayout. Information on the list view is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx

Check out the Grid App template under the Javascript section in Visual Studio 2012 (when you choose File -> New Project) for a sample.

Comment: i just want to know the grid simple how to do this

Comment: This is ok for aligning simple boxes, but not for complex UI. You cannot nest some UI controls inside `ListView` control.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox does give you this, but requires you rewire all of the behavior you get out of the box by using the winjs listview...(page nav, click events, data binding, etc)

Gridview will NOT allow you to have your data presented horizontally.

Comment: you can have ms-inline-grid

Comment: or orientation: horizontal;

Answer (score -3):

See http://jsfiddle.net/zuB3k/

If you are using `display:-ms-grid`, which is only supported by IE 10, you can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`, which follow w3c standards and are supported since version 8.

```
body {
    font-size:20px;
}

#content {
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.group {
    display:table-cell;
    padding-right:20px;
    vertical-align:top;

}

.group div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#888;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This post has a windows-8 tag meaning he's targeting IE10.

Comment: @JeremyFoster Yes, but it is better if more browsers support the code, isn't it?

Comment: If you were going to use more browsers, perhaps, but again if it's just Windows 8 then I would use the grid. It will save time and provide more power for the developer anyway.

Comment: @JeremyFoster More power? To do what the asker asked there's no need to use grids. And the standards should be followed always when it's possible, but -ms-grid is a vendor extension. If the asker wants a more complex layout which can't be done using `display:table-cell`, then he should use grids, but he hasn't said that. Moreover, my answer is completely correct, so you shouldn't downvote me only because you prefer another one; you should upvote the other one instead.

Comment: @Oriol - What you are missing is that the original poster is creating a Windows 8 application, not a web application that may run in multiple browsers.

Comment: @DarLom Well, but if you can write a Windows 8 application using CSS, I think it should be valid, and not a vendor extension

Comment: C'mon! 3 downvotes only because suggesting using standard and stable (CSS2.1 Recommendation) code instead of vendor extensions and unstable code (CSS Grid Layout, Working draft / CSS Flexible Box Layout Module, Candidate Recommendation)? CSS3 is amazing, but not needed if the same functionality can be achieved using CSS2.1.